# Zoom into Clusters (with Bing Maps) does not refresh clusters

Tags: bing-maps

I followed the Bing Maps docs for [Zoom into Clusters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750348.aspx). Since Microsoft only embeds a screenshot, here's a [working example](http://codepen.io/nachtigall/pen/KrvKYo). When you click on a cluster, notice that the cluster itself is not updated. Just pan the map very little bit, and then the map with its clusters is refreshed.

So either the Bing Maps documentation is broken or it is a Bing Maps bug.

Any idea for a workaround, e.g. how to force a map refresh after the map has zoomed in?

The relevant code (which does not update the map/clusters) is this, especially the last line:

```
function clusterClicked(e) {
    if (e.target.containedPushpins) {
        var locs = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = e.target.containedPushpins.length; i < len; i++) {
            //Get the location of each pushpin.
            locs.push(e.target.containedPushpins[i].getLocation());
        }

        //Create a bounding box for the pushpins.
        var bounds = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locs);

        //Zoom into the bounding box of the cluster. 
        //Add a padding to compensate for the pixel area of the pushpins.
        map.setView({ bounds: bounds, padding: 100 });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that has been fixed in the experimental branch. You can try this out by adding "&branch=experimental" to the map script URL. All fixes and features in the experimental branch will be rolled into the main release branch at the end of July.

Also, just so you are aware, there are a bunch of interactive code samples for V8 available here: http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#overview

Comment: The code is for a corporate intranet site. We are currently on the "frozen" branch as it's most stable. I don't think "release" is an option. When the fix be rolled into "frozen"? Or any other workaround for manually refreshing the clusters?

Comment: The frozen branch at the moment is no different than the main release branch. Frozen will likely be updated at the same time as the release branch for the first few updates as there are a decent number of bug fixes to push out. Both release and frozen branches are very stable. The release branch in V8 is as stable as previous version, likely more since we have a ton of automated tests that run regularly to monitor it. Even the experimental branch is very stable, but it gets updated 3+ times a day, so greater chance of an unexpected breaking bug.

Comment: A simple workaround is to add the following line of code after the setView call: 

clusterLayer.setPushpins(clusterLayer.getPushpins());