# Clustering stops working after Switching to Aerial in Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps

Following the Bing Maps docs for [Zoom into Clusters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750348.aspx), I face the following problem (Since Microsoft only embeds a screenshot, here's a [working example](http://codepen.io/nachtigall/pen/KrvKYo)):

1. ZoomIn (+) into the map a few times
2. Clustering and "De-Clustering" is working
3. Switch to Aerial
4. ZoomOut (-) a few times
5. Now the Clustering is **broken**

I switch to the `experimental` branch which seems to have fixed the issue. Any idea for a **workaround** to fix this also for the `release` or `frozen` branch?

Or would it be somehow possible to **only** use the `Road` layer. We do not need the `Aerial` layer, but I could not find only official documentation on how to disable `Aerial` (also I do not know if this would be against the legal Terms of Usage of Bing Maps)
The site is a big corporate intranet site. So using the  `experimental` branch is not an option.

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue that has been fixed in the experimental branch. You can try this out by adding "&branch=experimental" to the map script reference to try this out. This fix will be rolled into the main release branch at the end of July.

Comment: I don't like [copy'n'paste placeholder answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38229484/1129950) that do not address the actual question. As I've written I know the bug has been fixed in the experimental branch, this is why I asked for a workaround for the release or frozen branch.

Comment: This isn't a copy and paste answer. This is the official answer for this issue. I should know as I'm the Program Manager on the Bing Maps team leading the development of V8. There is no workaround for this issue. The frozen and release branches are only updated with things that are in the experimental or release branch.